# Checkboxes to display total not working as planned

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

#### This is my JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#inputs input').change(function() {
   if (this.checked) {
   $span = $('<span></span>');
   $span.text(this.value);
   $('#results').append($span);
   }
   else {
   $('span:contains('+this.value+')', '#results').remove();
   }
   });
   </script>
```

#### This is my html

```
<div id="inputs">
<input type="checkbox" name="amount" value="50.00"></input>
<input type="checkbox" name="amount" value="20.00"></input>
<input type="checkbox" name="amount" value="15.00"></input>
<input type="checkbox" name="amount" value="10.00"></input>
<span>Total: $</span><span id="results"></span>
```

Since the checkboxes all have  the same name it groups them so only one can be checked at a time, my question is:  How to make this so the value for the first checkbox checked goes away when another checkbox is checked.  This works only if you check a box then uncheck the same box, but if you check a box then check another you will see two values appear.  I can not figure this out. Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: 'Since the checkboxes all have the same name it groups them so only one can be checked at a time' That's not how a checkbox works. They can all be checked at the same time: https://jsfiddle.net/zfrodLvx/

Comment: this 'single choice" behavior belongs to `<input type="radio" name="">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this 'single choice" behavior belongs to radio input, not checkbox.

```js
$('#inputs input').change(function() {
   if (this.checked) {
   $span = $('<span></span>');
   $span.text('$'+ this.value);
   $('#results').html($span);
   }
   else {
   $('span:contains('+this.value+')', '#results').remove();
   }
   });
```

```css
body {
  background: skyblue;  
}
```

```html
<div id="inputs">
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="50.00" id=i50>
<label for="i50">50</label>  
  
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="20.00" id=i20>
<label for="i20">20</label>
  
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="15.00" id=i15>
<label for="i15">15</label>
  
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="10.00" id=i10>
<label for="i10">10</label>
  
<br><br><span>Selected: </span><span id="results"></span></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: be aware there is no close tag for input. check my last update please;

Comment: updated with $ symbol placed only after a selection be made;

Comment: How would I capture that this.value into a PHP value for processing?

Comment: sorry Tye, but my knowledge is only html, css and a little bit of javascript; I know nothing about php;

Comment: Thank you very much you saved my butt! =)

Comment: is it possible to create a hidden field in javascript with a name cost , so when it posts I can grab the value from the field using $cost = $_POST['cost']; ?

Comment: I don't get exactly what you mean, but i think maybe you're talking about 'global data-*' atributes (when you store a value in the html tag) example `<input type="text" data-cost="any data to be used later">` or maybe youre talking about store a value in a javascript variable? or yet maybe store a value in local storage/cookies? there's also a method very often used in php where they use hidden forms to data exchange between the pages...

Comment: Yes how would I store the this.value into a hidden from using JavaScript and retrieve it using PHP?

Comment: To pass a value to an input form using javascript: `document.getElementById("id").value = variable;`  or `document.getElementById("id").value = "value";` The php part, as I said, I don't know

Comment: it works perfectly!!!
      var cost = this.value;
      document.getElementById("passvalue").value = cost;

html:

    <input type="hidden" name="passvalue" id="passvalue" value="">

PHP:

      if(isset($_POST[ 'passvalue' ] ) ){
      $passvalue = (int) $_POST[ 'passvalue' ];

works brilliantly! Thank you so much!

Comment: additional info/examples [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)

Comment: sorry to keep posting here, is it possible to have a select box change the value of the first radio button?  Say I have a select box of classes some classes are $50 and some are $60, when I select the class from the select box it changes the price of the first radio button according to the value of the class I select?

Comment: What do you mean with "select box"? "check box" ?

Comment: i guess thats what youre looking for: [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzaQRV?editors=1010)

Comment: do the same as my [**last pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzaQRV?editors=1010) but with a drop down instead of a checkbox; if you fail, let me know and i help you;

Comment: I can't figure it out...basically your code above plus a drop down box that changes the price and label of the first radio button per option in the drop down...PHP is my language... I need to take a javascript class =)

Comment: ok [**here is the pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKZRdw?editors=1010) I cant go any further with this help; this kind of parallel conversation goes against the StackOverflow guidelines; the right way to do it would be open a new public question. I'm done on here.